# AS3, compare two functions

Tags: actionscript-3

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543910/as3-compare-two-functions) did not help.

I'm pushing functions onto an array, the array is a list of callbacks and I may want to remove a particular function.

I want to be able to loop through the array and remove a specific function. Something like this:

```
    public function clearCallback(callName:String = null, callback:Function = null) :void{
        if(callName == null){
            //remove all callbacks
            this.callbackFuncs = {};
        }
        else if(this.callbackFuncs.hasOwnProperty(callName)){
            if(callback == null){
                //remove all callbacks for this API call
                this.callbackFuncs[callName] = [];
            }
            else{
                //remove specific callback function
                for(var i:Number = 0, iLen:Number = (this.callbackFuncs[callName] as Array).length; i < iLen; i ++){
                    if(this.callbackFuncs[callName][i] == callback){
                        this.callbackFuncs[callName][i] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's the one commented `//remove specific callback function` that I'm having trouble with, how can I compare two functions?

In the code above, `callName` is not the function name, it's the name of the API call that the callback is registered to.

Comment: do you mean (this.callbackFuncs[callName][i] == callback) always returns false?

Answer (score 2):

You are not removing the callback you are just setting it to null, try something like the following :

```
public function clearCallback(callName:String = null, callback:Function = null) :void{
    if(callName == null){
        //remove all callbacks
        this.callbackFuncs = {};
    }
    else if(this.callbackFuncs.hasOwnProperty(callName)){
        if(callback == null){
            //remove all callbacks for this API call
            this.callbackFuncs[callName] = [];
        }
        else{
            //remove specific callback function
            for(var i:Number = (this.callbackFuncs[callName] as Array).length-1; i >=0; i --){
                if(this.callbackFuncs[callName][i] == callback){
                    this.callbackFuncs[callName].splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.